# Laravel default crypt method unexpected behaviour

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, laravel-5.1, aes

I am trying to encrypt json encoded string from laravel's default encryption. But i am not sure it's using the AES-256-CBC The reason behind this i am also trying same encryption from AES custom class.

What i did.

1. json_encode an array
2. set the key ,mode and blocksize in AES custom class and generating the token.
3. encrypt the token.
4. set encrypted token using setData
5. decrypt using AES custom class

Result is same as i was having in step1.
When i tried to encrypt (Crypt::encrypt($requestToken);) and decrypt (Crypt::decrypt($encrypt)) is giving correct result.
Now the problem is i am encrypting through (Crypt::encrypt($requestToken);) and want to decrypt through AES custom class. I am not sure that client is having laravel or not .

Comment: I think may be the issue with IV. So is there any way to set IV

Answer (score 0):

Check the Default key for encryption . Use same at both places

Comment: It's same on the both ends.

Comment: I dont think custom library and laravel library match . there may be different possibilities related to version or branch you pulled

Comment: For AES it should be same as my thinking. So there is no conflict with library.